# Switch within a loop cannot execute twice

Tags: android, for-loop, switch-statement

I am going to set Texts into a profile data fields by set texts into editTexts of previous input before user's modification and updating.

Following are the codes :

Original data is a String:
{k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v3, .....k9=v9}

```
public void parse(String foo) {
        String foo2 = foo.substring(1, foo.length() - 1);  // hack off braces

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(foo2, ",");
        String[] key = new String[20];
        String[] value = new String[20];
        int i = 0;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String thisToken = st.nextToken();        
            String[] keyValue = thisToken.split("=");
            try {
                key[i] = keyValue[0];
                value[i] = keyValue[1];
                setTextToFields(key[i], value[i]);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }          
        //for (i = 0; key[i] != null && value[i] != null && i <= 9; i++) {            
        //    setTextToFields(key[i], value[i]);

    //}
```

And I called setTextToFields method to set the texts, as following:

```
public void setTextToFields(String key, String value) {
        String dateOfBirth = null;

        switch (key) {
            case "dateOfBirth":
                dateOfBirth = value;
                try {
                    etYear.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(0, 4), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    etMonth.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(5, 7), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    etDay.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(8), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            case "firstName":
                etFirstName.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "lastName":
                etLastName.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "country":
                etCountry.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "city":
                etCity.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "iDNumber":
                etIDNumber.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "postCode":
                etPostCode.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "mobilePhoneNumber":
                etMobilePhoneNumber.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "province":
                etProvince.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "address":
                etAddress.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Nothing set to text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
}
```

When I called the second time or more of this setTextToFields method, the switch choose only to the default and set nothing to editText views.

Please help and let me know why.

Comment: I would say no it does not. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the right way to solve my problem.

The key[i] passed to the method is not trimmed.  So, just add trim() behind key.

```
switch (key.trim()) {
            case "dateOfBirth":
                dateOfBirth = value;
                try {
                    etYear.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(0, 4), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    etMonth.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(5, 7), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    etDay.setText(dateOfBirth.substring(8), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            case "firstName":
                etFirstName.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "lastName":
                etLastName.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "country":
                etCountry.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "city":
                etCity.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "iDNumber":
                etIDNumber.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "postCode":
                etPostCode.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "mobilePhoneNumber":
                etMobilePhoneNumber.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "province":
                etProvince.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            case "address":
                etAddress.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                return;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Nothing set to text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Should you be incrementing `i` within the while loop?

You've only set key0 and value0. The remaining are null, so the for-loop and the end won't be entered except once.

Also, you can update the regex to capture all the spaces around the equals

```
int i = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String thisToken = st.nextToken();        
    String[] keyValue = thisToken.split("\\s*=\\s*");
    try {
        key[i] = keyValue[0];
        value[i] = keyValue[1];
```

Alternatively, just put `setTextToFields(key[i], value[i]);` within the while-loop

I'd also suggest a HashMap instead of two arrays.

Comment: That's a nice catch :)

Comment: Much better than my original answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The key value did pass to setTextToFields in both ways, however, the switch doesn't work.  A monitoring Toast tells me "nothing set to text", not even once.

Comment: My answer was still technically, correct, though since you've not set all the key values. You could put `key[i].trim()` as the parameter of the method.

Comment: Thanks, just know how to accept an answer from your tip.

Comment: You're welcome. Accepting your own answer based on an existing answer isn't really fair, though